# Why is my mail function displays utf8 characters in the subject but not in the message itself?

Tags: php, utf-8

I receive email correctly. For safety purpose I've hidden my recaptcha secret key but this part is working fine. When I receive the email the subject's special characters are displayed correctly. However, if french accents are sent in the message (`éèàç`, for example) the are displayed like this (`Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã§`). As this is a french website, this is a real problem. I tried `utf8_encode($message)` in the mail function but to no avail. I looked at other stackoverflow posts but none helped. Also in the message this part is displayed as `Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'`. Can this be avoided?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['valider'])) {
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $privateKey = "secret";

            $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privateKey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $data = json_decode($response);
            if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){

                    $rusty = 'email@email.com';
                    $destinataire = $_POST["email"];
                    $message = utf8_encode(wordwrap($_POST['message']));
                    $subject = "Question pour la méthode EtVoilà";
                    $headers = 'From:' .  $destinataire."\n";
                    $header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
                    if(mail($rusty,'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=',$message,$header_ . $headers)) {
                    header('Location: index.php?MessagePass=True');
            } else {
                    header('Location: index.php?MessageError=True');
                    }
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the html page is in utf-8 (<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the function iconv does the trick for me, here's the new part in case someone has the same problem. I just add the second line in the code below.

```
                    $message = wordwrap($_POST['message']);
                    $message = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $message);
```

Comment: if you use utf-8 *everywhere* there is no need to convert.